# Unable to fetch elements from XML as getting error "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have written a code to remove countries of those ranks which are not present in list `lis` from  `tes.xml` and generating updated xml  `output.xml` after removing the countries. But getting error while generating the output xml
XML:

```
tes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <continents>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">123456</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>yes</pretty>
      </zones>
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">789045</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">67846464</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
  </continents>  
</data>
```

code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('tes.xml')

lis = ["123456"]
root = tree.getroot()
print('root is', root)
print(type(root))

for continent in root.findall('.//continents'):
    for country in continent:
        rank = country.find('state/rank').text
        print(rank)
        if rank not in lis:
            continent.remove(country)

tree.write('outpu.xml')
```

console output: It is not even printing all the ranks from XML i.e. 67846464 is skipped so this rank will also be printed in the `output.xml` though it is not there in the list

```
root is <Element 'data' at 0x7f5929a9d8b0>
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
123456
789045
```

Current output: having 2 ids 123456 and 67846464

```
<data>
  <continents>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">123456</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>yes</pretty>
      </zones>
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">67846464</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
  </continents>  
</data>
```

Expected output: only 123456 should come as 67846464 is not in the list

```
<data>
  <continents>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">123456</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>yes</pretty>
      </zones>
    </country>
  </continents>  
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that country is not contained in `root` element. It is contained in the `continents` tag. One solution to the problem is to iterate over `continents` in `root` and then check for `rank` of `country`. This can be done using the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('tes.xml')

lis = ['2', '5']
root = tree.getroot()
print('root is', root)
print(type(root))

for continent in root.findall('.//continents'):
    for country in continent:
        rank = country.find('state/rank').text
        print(rank)
        if rank not in lis:
            continent.remove(country)

tree.write('outpu.xml')
```

**Edit**

We can't simply iterate over countries in continents using

`for country in continent`
because continent is `<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>` and to iterate over it we must use `findall`. The updated code is as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('tes.xml')

lis = ['123456']
root = tree.getroot()
print('root is', root)
print(type(root))

for continent in root.findall('.//continents'):
    for country in continent.findall('.//country'):
        rank = country.find('state/rank').text
        print(rank)
        if rank not in lis:
            print('country is', country)
            print(country in continent)
            continent.remove(country)

tree.write('outpu.xml')
```

Comment: thanks. I tried this on my xml which has around 10 countries and somehow it is not identifying and hence printing all the ranks and hence countries of those non printed ranks are also comingi n output.xml

Comment: The code works for the given data and produces the required output. Can you provide more details about the problem or the data you are working on

Comment: I have updated the xml and rank values to string. you can see that ```67846464``` should not be in output but it is coming