# Unable to fetch expected items properly from XML using lxml in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have written a code to remove countries of those ranks which are not present in list `lis` from  `tes.xml` and generating updated xml  `output.xml` after removing the countries. But those countries are also coming in output which are not there in the list
XML:

```
tes.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <continents>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">123456</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>yes</pretty>
      </zones>
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">789045</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">67846464</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
  </continents>  
</data>
```

code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('tes.xml')

lis = ["123456"]
root = tree.getroot()
print('root is', root)
print(type(root))

for continent in root.findall('.//continents'):
    for country in continent:
        rank = country.find('state/rank').text
        print(rank)
        if rank not in lis:
            continent.remove(country)

tree.write('outpu.xml')
```

console output: It is not even printing all the ranks from XML i.e. `67846464` is skipped so this rank will also be printed in the `output.xml` though it is not there in the list

```
root is <Element 'data' at 0x7f5929a9d8b0>
<class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>
123456
789045
```

Current output: having 2 ids `123456` and `67846464`

```
<data>
  <continents>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">123456</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>yes</pretty>
      </zones>
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">67846464</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N" />
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
  </continents>  
</data>
```

Expected output: only 123456 should come as 67846464 is not in the list

```
<data>
  <continents>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">123456</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E" />
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W" />
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>yes</pretty>
      </zones>
    </country>
  </continents>  
</data>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to fetch elements from XML as getting error "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list" in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62588526/unable-to-fetch-elements-from-xml-as-getting-error-valueerror-list-removex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work fine with BeautifulSoup.  I just stuck the XML code in as a string:

```
input = """
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <continents>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">123456</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>yes</pretty>
      </zones>
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">789045</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
    <country>
      <state>
        <rank updated="yes">67846464</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <gpc>59900</gpc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
      </state>
      <zones>
        <pretty>No</pretty>
      </zones>
      <market>
        <pretty>cool</pretty>
      </market>  
    </country>
  </continents>  
</data>
"""
```

And here's the real coding part:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

lis = ["123456"]

# Turn the XML into one big BS object
soup = BeautifulSoup(input, "lxml")

# Parse through to find all <country> tags.  
# From each, grab the <rank> value.  If the rank value
# is not in the list, delete the respective <country> tag.
for country in soup.find_all("country"):
    rank = country.find("rank").text
    if rank not in lis:
        country.decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```

This gives me the expected output of the matching country. When I change `lis` to "`["123456", "67846464"]`", I get the expected 2 countries to output.

Comment: but what if xml is too large  like it has 60000 countries then can I put the whole xml in input variable?

Comment: I only pasted it in there as a string just to get the code working.  If the XML file is that huge, then obviously you'll want to read it in some other way. Off-hand I don't know how well BeautifulSoup itself handles huge input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is you are removing the elements from the `continent` while iterating.

```
for continent in root.findall('.//continents'):
    for country in continent.findall('./country'):
        if country.find('state/rank').text not in lis:
            continent.remove(country)
```